# Liquibase change-log in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to figure out how the project works.
It uses Liquibase:

[image]

The problem is that the .yaml file is not in the classpath folder so it's not accessible.
Error:

[image]

How to let Spring Boot know where is the change-log?

Comment: I'm not sure if it still works, but colleague of mine was hacking this with something like: `classpath:data-access-jpa.jar!db/changelog/db/changelog-master.yaml` so you have also there the name of jar.

Answer (score 1):

Use property name as

> spring.liquibase.changeLog

not

> liquibase.changeLog