# liquibase change-log file path

Tags: liquibase

It is a question same as
[Liquibase change-log in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528821/liquibase-change-log-in-spring-boot).

In the picture below I have two modules.
notification-service-main and notification-service-liquibase
So, earlier I only had the main module where all the liquibase scripts were saved . The reason to create another module to keep all the scripts so that I can leverage initcontainers concept of kubernetes ( this is what I'm trying to achieve)
But when I moved all the scripts and changelog files to another module. My test files needed reference of the changelog files to run. In this scenario I want to point to the files from my main module

spring.liquibase.change-log: classpath: {the_path} this is the property that I'm using (it is in the yml format just for convenience sake I wrote it this way)
I have used absolute path but it doesn't work . Is there any other properties which I can use .

[For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vF8B.png)

Comment: Are you using Spring or any other framework? Did you try to point the property to a file-path ? What are your modules ? Please give a concrete [example].

Comment: I have provided the project structure and yes I'm using spring framework